# Apple changed allowed vector format in Metal

Tags: ios, metal

It seems from iOS 12.1.1  Metal shaders that reference vectors in the form (float4)(1,2,3,4) silently get parsed as something else - think (1,1,1,1). This applies to all vector formats. Only way to fix it is to remove the paranthesis around the type. Some will say the paranthesis were extrenuous to begin with. But we had a lot of code that was working and suddenly started siently miscalculating because of this switchup.

My question is whether this is a Metal bug, or just Apple being syntax-Nazis and tightening up stuff for no good reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should never have worked in the first place.

The comma-separated, parenthesized list of values in `(float4)(1,2,3,4)` gets treated as an application of the [*comma operator*](https://codassium.com/blog/the-forgotten-comma-operator/), not a parameter list for a constructor, since you've parenthesized the type as well. There are many ways to initialize a `float4` from either 1 or 4 components. These produce the vector { 1, 2, 3, 4 }:

```
float4 f = float4(1, 2, 3, 4);
float4 f(1, 2, 3, 4);
float4 f = (float4){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
float4 f{1, 2, 3, 4};
float4 f = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

and these produce the vector { 1, 1, 1, 1 }:

```
float4 f = { 1 };
float4 f(1);
float4 f = 1;
float4 f = (float4)1;
```

Your example, while syntactically valid, doesn't produce the expected result, because that syntax doesn't mean what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the reference on comma operator. Good reference. Not sure how it was passing before this update (it was ported from OpenCL to Metal like that). I guess it comes down to precedence of resolving the parentheses around type.